# how to pass the arguments to the call back function in catch function in javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, asynccallback

I was doing the code  and just felt the need ...that
that I want to pass the extra argument ie  msg to the callback function `renderError()` function along with the default error argumet which is generated by the catch function itself  in the catch function

also I can't do this way
 `.catch(renderError(err,'this is msg'));`
as it will become `function call` and as per my knowledge We only have to **pass** the callback function to the `higher order function`  rather than calling it there

- so how can i pass it so that my msg argument

Note - Please dont refer other code as I have taken a short snippet form my code  --  I just want to pass the argument to my call back function which is `renderError()`

```
const renderError = function (err, msg) {
  console.log(err);

  countriesContainer.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', msg);
  countriesContainer.style.opacity = 1;
};

const getCountryData = function (country) {
  fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${country}`)
    .then(
      response => response.json()
      // err => console.log(err)
    )
    .then(data => {
      renderCountry(data[0]);
      const neighbour = data[0].borders[0];

      if (!neighbour) return;

      return fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/alpha/${neighbour}`);
    })
    .then(
      response => response.json()
      // err => console.log(err)
    )
    .then(data => renderCountry(data, 'neighbour'))
    .catch(renderError);           //  ---->> here I want to pass the message that will be 
                                   //  display along with the call back function 
};
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  getCountryData('germany');
});
```

Comment: `.catch(error => renderError(error, msg))`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you `renderError` call in a function that exposes the `error` value.

```
.catch(error => {
  renderError(error, 'Your custom error message');
});
```

Comment: is there any way to pass it directly rather than wrapping it

Comment: Unfortunately not.